# Javascript function arguments with "-"

Tags: javascript, syntax

I came across with strange issue. In my js file when i wrote a function with arguments and one of them was 'file-name'

```
function fileSize(id, file-name) {
  // some code
}
```

This gave me an error, but when i changed argument name into "file_name", error was gone.

```
function fileSize(id, file_name) {
  // some code
}
```

So why this happened??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, identifier names cannot have `-` in them, but `_` is allowed. Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables),

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).
>
> Starting with JavaScript 1.5, you can use ISO 8859-1 or Unicode letters such as å and ü in identifiers. You can also use the \uXXXX Unicode escape sequences as characters in identifiers.

So, only allowed special characters are `_` and `$`.

Comment: your conclusion is not comprehensive; ex: function x(ƒ){}

Comment: @dandavis Yes, that is correct. What is wrong with that?

Comment: what you call "letters" != A-Z + a-z, and that part can be mis-leading to causal readers of your answer. in fact, i'm not even sure what a "letter" means. some unicode is a letter, some isn't. i'm not saying you're wrong at all, just a little over-restrictive.

Comment: if arguments/variables are termed _identifier_ s in the source text, yeah, i think running "var ƒ=1;" in the console without error falsifies the theory. that's [ALT]+[1][5][9] btw, not a unicode sequence...

Comment: looks perfect and comprehensive, and shed some light for me to boot. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the `-` token is used by the subtract operator. Therefore, when the parser encounters:

```
file-name
```

it interprets it as two variables, `file` and `name`, with `name` being subtracted from `file`.

Since this is an expression, and expressions are invalid in argument declaration, the function declaration itself becomes invalid.

While we *can* design the language such that the `-` symbol does not mean subtract when in argument declarations we cannot use the argument later in the code because there is no way for the language to differentiate between `file-name` and `file - name`. Other languages may have syntax to deal with this but javascript doesn't (it sort of does for object properties using the `object["file-name"]` syntax but not for local variables).

This is why javascript disallow the `-` symbol in variable and function names.